# java make each line an array or list

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have the following text in a textfile:
aaa:a,b,c
bbb:d,f

How can I make a list of arrays,in which each array contains only the words after ":" and without the commas 
for example ,array1 will be : [a b c]
array2 will be [d f]

I have this code so far but i get as an output :
[aaa:a, b, c]
[bbb:d,f]

```
// this list will store all the created arrays
      List<String[]> arrays = new ArrayList<String[]>();

      // use a BufferedReader to get the handy readLine() function
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("scor.txt"));


      for (String line1 = reader.readLine(); line1 != null; 
              line1 = reader.readLine()) {
          String[] floatStrings = line1.split(",");
          String[] textline = new String[floatStrings.length];
          for (int i = 0; i < textline.length; ++i) {
              textline[i] = floatStrings[i];
          }
          arrays.add(textline);
      }
      for (String[] arr : arrays) {
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
      }

  }
```

I changed the code a bit:

```
String[] textline = new String[floatStrings.length-1];
          for (int i = 0; i < textline.length; ++i) {
              String[] newTextlineWithoutFirst = Arrays.copyOfRange(floatStrings, 1, floatStrings.length);
              textline[i] = newTextlineWithoutFirst[i];

          }
          arrays.add(textline);
      }
      for (String[] arr : arrays) {
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try splitting on `:` first then split `[1]` on `,`...

```
 for (String line1 = reader.readLine(); line1 != null; line1 = reader.readLine()) {
      String[] splitString = line1.split(":");
      splitString = splitString[1].split(",");
      String[] textline = new String[splitString.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < textline.length; ++i) {
          textline[i] = splitString[i];
      }
      arrays.add(textline);
  }
```